# Grafana /api/dashboards/uid/ result miss datasource id

Tags: grafana, grafana-api, grafana-dashboard

When I use grafana */api/dashboards/uid/xyz123* API, I get all definitions of dashboard xyz123, except the datasources’ ids. It returns dashboard json with *“datasource”: null*,
If I export it via GUI (share->export) it does have datasources’ ids.
Pls advise.

Comment: If an API provided by any tool is not working as expected, you should report this to the maintainers of the API. Unless you share code, this is off-topic on StackOverflow

Comment: Are you sure you are comparing the same panels within your dashboard? For me, datasource is always `null` if the default datasource is used. Only if a non-default datasource is used, its name is written in the JSON. And it is like that in the GUI, in the export, and in the API response.